# flexDirection doesn't work with scrollview

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm trying to make a grid with ScrollView but I don't get the expected result

```
<ScrollView style={{flex:1, flexDirection:'row', flexWrap:'wrap'}}>
    <Text style={{width:100, height:100, backgroundColor:'red'}} >Text</Text>
            <Text style={{width:100, height:100, backgroundColor:'red'}} >Text</Text>
            <Text style={{width:100, height:100, backgroundColor:'red'}} >Text</Text>
            <Text style={{width:100, height:100, backgroundColor:'red'}} >Text</Text>
</ScrollView>
```

RESULT:
[image]

Answer (score 5):

You should add style to your ScrollView contentContainerStyle to have flexDirection: 'row' and flexWrap: 'wrap'

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Text, StyleSheet, ScrollView } from 'react-native';

export default class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <ScrollView contentContainerStyle={styles.container}>
        <Text style={styles.cell}>
        </Text>
      </ScrollView>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
    flexWrap: 'wrap'
  },
  cell: {
    width: 100,
    height: 100,
    backgroundColor: 'red'
  },
});
```

Comment: That's so weird but it works 

Answer (score 0):

Wrap each Text into View

```
<View>
   <Text style={{width:100, height:100, backgroundColor:'red'}}>Text</Text>
</View>
```